# Why does the value of the $id variable change to a string automatically on the WAMP server, but not on the Bluehost server?

Tags: php, android, wamp

In PHP, the $id variable is expected to receive an integer value from the client side. However, when the id value is sent as an integer from the client side to the PHP script using the POST request method, it is automatically converted to a string type in PHP when the script is uploaded on the WAMP server. On the other hand, when the script is uploaded on the Bluehost server, the id value remains an integer and is not converted to a string, which is what I want.

**Here is a simple PHP script:**

```
<?php

$id = $_POST["id"];

if (is_int($id))
    echo "It is integer"; // It will print this if the PHP script was uploaded to the Bluehost server.
else if (is_string($id))
    echo "It is string"; // It will print this if the PHP script was uploaded to the WAMP server.
```

**The id value that is sent from the client side is via an Android app, and this is how I send the id value to the PHP script:**

*RetrofitManager class*

```
public class RetrofitManager {

    private static RetrofitManager.Api api;

    public static RetrofitManager.Api getApi() {
        if (api == null)
            api = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.151.5.721/API/")
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES).writeTimeout(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES).connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(Api.class);

        return api;
    }

    public interface Api {

        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("Countries/Get.php")
        Single<CountryModelResponse> getCountries(@Field("id") int countryId);

    }

}
```

*CountriesRepository class*

```
public class CountriesRepository {

    public LiveData<Object> getCountries(Context context) {
        MutableLiveData<Object> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        PublishSubject<String> retrySubject = PublishSubject.create();

        RetrofitManager.getApi().getCountries(Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.activityMainBinding.activityMainFragmentContainerViewContainer).getPreviousBackStackEntry() == null ? SharedPreferencesManager.getIntegerValue(context, SharedPreferencesManager.Keys.COUNTRY_ID.name()) : -1)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(mutableLiveData::setValue)
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                LinkedHashSet<Object> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                linkedHashSet.add(!Utils.isInternetConnected(context) ? 100 : throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException ? 200 : 300);
                linkedHashSet.add(retrySubject);
                mutableLiveData.setValue(linkedHashSet);
            })
            .retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> throwableFlowable.flatMap(throwable -> retrySubject.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.DROP).take(1), (throwable, s) -> s))
            .subscribe(countryModelResponse -> {
                if (countryModelResponse.getRequestStatus() == 100)
                    mutableLiveData.setValue(countryModelResponse);
                else {
                    LinkedHashSet<Object> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
                    linkedHashSet.add(300);
                    linkedHashSet.add(retrySubject);
                    mutableLiveData.setValue(linkedHashSet);
                }
            });

        return mutableLiveData;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure why this difference in behavior occurs between the two servers.

I'm using the latest version of PHP and the WAMP server.

Comment: Show the code / other information to support what you said please

Comment: @KenLee Okay, sorry. I modified my question and included the PHP script.

Comment: Everything in `$_POST` is strings. The format for posting values doesn't provide any way to specify the type.

Comment: For form input, use `is_numeric()` instead -- see [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Comment: The comments in the code are the opposite of what you say in the question.

Comment: I know how to convert a string to an integer, but I want to know why the Bluehost server does not automatically convert the integer to a string, while the WAMP server does.

Comment: Are you running the same version of PHP on both?

Comment: It's the opposite, Bluehost is converting the string to an integer. I don't know why or how it's doing this.

Comment: @Barmar On the Bluehost server, I am on shared hosting and the PHP version is 7.4.

Comment: @Barmar I am using the latest version of PHP on the WAMP server.

Comment: How did you send the $_POST variable(s) ? (please show that part too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the requests over HTTP as sent as strings.  We have to cast it according to our needs.  In your case the behavior is strange.  Try checking the PHP version at both ends and see if they are the same.

Comment: The other end is usually a browser, which doesn't have PHP.

Comment: Whatever is happening at BlueHost is very unexpected behavior. Somewhere along the way your variable is being cast to integer. Perhaps there is some sanitization or filtering happening.

Comment: @PatrickMoore I have been considering the possibility that the Bluehost company may have implemented a hidden file on their server that automatically converts variables from HTTP requests from string to their correct data type. However, I am unsure if this is actually the case. Do you believe this to be a feasible possibility?

Comment: @TahaSami it would make sense. Maybe Bluehost is injecting runtime code that sanitizes the data, and at this time PHP is automatically recasting numeric strings to integers (as expected). I was considering if there was some difference in running PHP in FastCGI or if they somehow automatically containerized your application? I've not experienced this... doesn't mean it isn't this way. It's a puzzle to be sure.

Comment: @PatrickMoore I believe that Bluehost does not modify any variables in the HTTP request, as when I use Postman to send the id value (for example, 5), it is still being received as a string type in the PHP script, rather than being converted to an integer type. This has caused me confusion.

Comment: The possibility of modifying the response value by the hosting companies is very less.  Another possibility would be (W)AMP.  Might be a windows issue.  To confirm, try to host the same set of codebases in any other server other than Bluehost and execute it.  I belive it will behave the same way it did in Bluehost, if that is the case we can make sure it is probably because of the PHP-windows issue.